# C++: How can I pass data from an object to an array of another object via a third object?

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14

### ** Link to the original question is given at the bottom **

### *Refer to "Course.h", "Course.cpp" and "main.cpp" code*

Student.h

```
#pragma once

#include <string>

using namespace std;

class Student {
    private:
        string fname;
        string lname;

        int age;
        string address;
        string city;
        string phone;
    public:
        Student();
        ~Student();

        Student(string, string, int, string, string, string);


};
```

Student.cpp

```
#include "Student.h"
#include <string>

using namespace std;

Student::Student(){
}
Student::~Student(){
}

Student::Student(string _fname, string _lname, int _age, string _address, string _city, string _phone) {
    fname = _fname;
    lname = _lname;

    age = _age;
    address = _address;
    city = _city;
    phone = _phone;
}
```

Course.h

```
#pragma once

#include <string>
#include "Student.h"

class Course {
    private:
        string course_name = "Intermediate C++";
        Student student[3];    // Need data of three students
    public:
        Course();
        ~Course();

        // *Create some constructor to pass student data*

        string getCourseName();
};
```

Course.cpp

```
#include "Course.h"
#include "Student.h"

using namespace std;

Course::Course(){
}
Course::~Course(){
}

string Course::getCourseName() {
    return this->course_name;
}
```

Main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>

#include "Student.h"
#include "Course.h"
using namespace std;

int main() {
    Student student1("fName_1","lName_1",18,"address_1","city_1","phone_1");
    Student student2("fName_2","lName_2",19,"address_2","city_2","phone_2");
    Student student3("fName_3","lName_3",20,"address_3","city_3","phone_3");

    Course *course = new Course;



    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

---

**Now**, how do I pass all the three student objects to the course object?

---

**Original Question Link**: https://courses.edx.org/courses/course-v1:Microsoft+DEV210.2x+3T2016/info

**Refer to "Module Two" -> "Lab"**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create methods named `getters` and `setters`. They are the best way to pass information between objections. For example, if you want to get to know what the name of the student is, you simply make a public method for your Student:

`string Student::getFname() {return fname; }`

The solve of your problem is just making an appropriate method for setting the students in your course. It might look like that:

```
void Course::setStudents(Student s1, Student s2, Student s3)
{
   student[0] = s1;
   student[1] = s2;
   student[2] = s3;
}
```

Or just make another method to add them on a specific position.

Answer (score 1):

Since the student array is private you need a class method to access it, so you add a new method to course, for example:

1. To access the array itself
2. To add elements
3. ...

For example, 2 would be like:

**Course.h:**

```
...
public:
    bool addStudent(Student s, short pos);
```

**Course.c:**

```
bool addStudent(Student s, short pos){
    if(pos >=0 && pos <= 2){
        student[pos] = s;
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

And 
**main.c:**

```
int main() {
    Student student1("fName_1","lName_1",18,"address_1","city_1","phone_1");
    Student student2("fName_2","lName_2",19,"address_2","city_2","phone_2");
    Student student3("fName_3","lName_3",20,"address_3","city_3","phone_3");

    Course *course = new Course;

    course->addStudent(student1,0);
    course->addStudent(student2,1);
    course->addStudent(student3,2);

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```